# Flutter: Extending and Overriding (DatePicker)

Tags: flutter, datepicker, overriding, extends

I am seeking to highlight public holidays in the DatePicker. Other posts have suggested the table_calendar package. If this is the solution that's fine, but I don't understand why.

I'd also be seeking to add an additional TimePicker which would just accept text entry, or move from hour to minute on certain conditions. I'm currently building a Windows App using Flutter, so the mobile focussed date and time pickers do feel like they get in the way.

Can't we extend and override portions of DatePicker? Then create a custom builder for it?

I'm relatively new, and overriding, and builders are concepts I'm coming to terms with. Seeking an understanding of why it's not possible via extension at this stage.

Research in Stackoverflow have indicated that it can't be done. My rudimentary understanding of extending classes suggests it should be possible.